# sails lift fail at typeerror this._normalizeAssociations is not a function

Tags: sails.js

After checkout a project from GitLab, I issued 'sails lift' in the cmd, it is OK. I sent Ctrl-C and issue 'sails lift' again, here is the output:

```
info: Starting app...

info: 
info: 
info:    Sails              <|
info:    v0.10.5             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------' 
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: 
info: Server lifted in `D:\CoachGarden\meetup2`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Sun Feb 28 2016 10:02:45 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)

debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\model\lib\model.js:54
  this._normalizeAssociations();
       ^

TypeError: this._normalizeAssociations is not a function
    at module.exports (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\model\lib\model.js:54:8)
    at child [as constructor] (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\utils\extend.js:17:39)
    at new bound (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\lodash\dist\lodash.js:726:29)
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\basic.js:388:23
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at returnResults (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\basic.js:387:21)
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\basic.js:272:16
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\operations.js:82:7
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:49:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:227:20)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:206:22)
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\operations.js:433:11
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\operations.js:572:5
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:49:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:227:20)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:206:22)
    at _buildChildOpts (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\operations.js:461:9)
    at _execChildOpts (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\operations.js:429:8)
    at D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\operations.js:80:10
    at wrapper (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\node_modules\lodash\index.js:3602:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\utils\normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (D:\CoachGarden\meetup2\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\utils\normalize.js:320:18)
```

After search with Google, I give "issue 'del .tmp\localDiskDb.db', then issue 'sails lift'" a try, 'sails lift' works again. Now I need to del that Db file every time to get sails successfully lifted.

here is the content of .tmp\localDiskDb.db:

```
{
  "data": {
    "answer": [],
    "comment": [],
    "event": [],
    "group": [],
    "mail": [],
    "paper": [],
    "photo": [],
    "privilege": [
      {
        "userid": "00000001",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "global",
        "role": "administrator",
        "creategroup": "yes",
        "deletegroup": "yes",
        "editgroup": "yes",
        "createevent": "yes",
        "deleteevent": "yes",
        "editevent": "yes",
        "addgroupmember": "yes",
        "deletegroupmember": "yes",
        "exportgroupmember": "yes",
        "addeventmember": "yes",
        "deleteeventmember": "yes",
        "exporteventmember": "yes",
        "uploadpaper": "yes",
        "deletepaper": "yes",
        "gettestreport": "yes",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "yes",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.632Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.632Z",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "userid": "00000002",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "global",
        "role": "actingadministrator",
        "creategroup": "yes",
        "deletegroup": "yes",
        "editgroup": "yes",
        "createevent": "yes",
        "deleteevent": "yes",
        "editevent": "yes",
        "addgroupmember": "yes",
        "deletegroupmember": "yes",
        "exportgroupmember": "yes",
        "addeventmember": "yes",
        "deleteeventmember": "yes",
        "exporteventmember": "yes",
        "uploadpaper": "yes",
        "deletepaper": "yes",
        "gettestreport": "yes",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "yes",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.648Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.648Z",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "userid": "00000003",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "global",
        "role": "globalspecial",
        "creategroup": "yes",
        "deletegroup": "no",
        "editgroup": "yes",
        "createevent": "yes",
        "deleteevent": "yes",
        "editevent": "yes",
        "addgroupmember": "yes",
        "deletegroupmember": "yes",
        "exportgroupmember": "yes",
        "addeventmember": "yes",
        "deleteeventmember": "yes",
        "exporteventmember": "yes",
        "uploadpaper": "yes",
        "deletepaper": "yes",
        "gettestreport": "yes",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "yes",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.659Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.659Z",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "userid": "00000004",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "global",
        "role": "globaluser",
        "creategroup": "yes",
        "deletegroup": "no",
        "editgroup": "no",
        "createevent": "no",
        "deleteevent": "no",
        "editevent": "no",
        "addgroupmember": "no",
        "deletegroupmember": "no",
        "exportgroupmember": "no",
        "addeventmember": "no",
        "deleteeventmember": "no",
        "exporteventmember": "no",
        "uploadpaper": "no",
        "deletepaper": "no",
        "gettestreport": "no",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "no",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.672Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.672Z",
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "userid": "00000011",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "group",
        "role": "groupowner",
        "creategroup": "no",
        "deletegroup": "no",
        "editgroup": "no",
        "createevent": "no",
        "deleteevent": "no",
        "editevent": "no",
        "addgroupmember": "no",
        "deletegroupmember": "no",
        "exportgroupmember": "no",
        "addeventmember": "no",
        "deleteeventmember": "no",
        "exporteventmember": "no",
        "uploadpaper": "no",
        "deletepaper": "no",
        "gettestreport": "no",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "no",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.683Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.683Z",
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "userid": "00000012",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "group",
        "role": "groupactingowner",
        "creategroup": "no",
        "deletegroup": "no",
        "editgroup": "yes",
        "createevent": "yes",
        "deleteevent": "yes",
        "editevent": "yes",
        "addgroupmember": "yes",
        "deletegroupmember": "yes",
        "exportgroupmember": "yes",
        "addeventmember": "yes",
        "deleteeventmember": "yes",
        "exporteventmember": "yes",
        "uploadpaper": "yes",
        "deletepaper": "yes",
        "gettestreport": "yes",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "yes",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.694Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.694Z",
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "userid": "00000013",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "group",
        "role": "groupspecial",
        "creategroup": "no",
        "deletegroup": "no",
        "editgroup": "yes",
        "createevent": "yes",
        "deleteevent": "no",
        "editevent": "yes",
        "addgroupmember": "yes",
        "deletegroupmember": "yes",
        "exportgroupmember": "yes",
        "addeventmember": "yes",
        "deleteeventmember": "yes",
        "exporteventmember": "yes",
        "uploadpaper": "yes",
        "deletepaper": "yes",
        "gettestreport": "yes",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "yes",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.704Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.704Z",
        "id": 7
      },
      {
        "userid": "00000014",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "group",
        "role": "groupuser",
        "creategroup": "no",
        "deletegroup": "no",
        "editgroup": "no",
        "createevent": "yes",
        "deleteevent": "no",
        "editevent": "no",
        "addgroupmember": "no",
        "deletegroupmember": "no",
        "exportgroupmember": "yes",
        "addeventmember": "no",
        "deleteeventmember": "no",
        "exporteventmember": "yes",
        "uploadpaper": "no",
        "deletepaper": "no",
        "gettestreport": "no",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "no",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.721Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.721Z",
        "id": 8
      },
      {
        "userid": "10239936",
        "groupid": null,
        "scope": "global",
        "role": "administrator",
        "creategroup": "yes",
        "deletegroup": "yes",
        "editgroup": "yes",
        "createevent": "yes",
        "deleteevent": "yes",
        "editevent": "yes",
        "addgroupmember": "yes",
        "deletegroupmember": "yes",
        "exportgroupmember": "yes",
        "addeventmember": "yes",
        "deleteeventmember": "yes",
        "exporteventmember": "yes",
        "uploadpaper": "yes",
        "deletepaper": "yes",
        "gettestreport": "yes",
        "createtag": "yes",
        "deletetag": "yes",
        "constructor": {
          "__super__": {}
        },
        "toObject": {},
        "save": {},
        "destroy": {},
        "_defineAssociations": {},
        "_normalizeAssociations": {},
        "_cast": {},
        "validate": {},
        "toJSON": {},
        "createdAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.736Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-28T02:10:00.736Z",
        "id": 9
      }
    ],
    "tag": [],
    "user": [],
    "comment_likeby__user_likedcomments": [],
    "event_user__user_events": [],
    "group_user__user_group": []
  },
  "schema": {
    "answer": {
      "paper": {
        "type": "integer",
        "model": "paper",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "paper"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "owner"
      },
      "reply": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "score": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "comment": {
      "content": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "likecount": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "createdby": {
        "type": "string",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "createdby"
      },
      "event": {
        "type": "integer",
        "model": "event",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "event"
      },
      "replyto": {
        "type": "integer",
        "model": "comment",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "replyto"
      },
      "maincomment": {
        "type": "integer",
        "model": "comment",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "maincomment"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "event": {
      "topic": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "desc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "address": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "begindate": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "enddate": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "phoDescription": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultsTo": "No Description, Add it!"
      },
      "group": {
        "type": "integer",
        "model": "group",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "group"
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "owner"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "group": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "unique": true
      },
      "desc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "owner"
      },
      "groupfd": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "tags": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "mail": {
      "to": {
        "type": "array"
      },
      "subject": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "contentWithTemplate": {
        "type": "json",
        "defaultsTo": null
      },
      "attachments": {
        "type": "json",
        "defaultsTo": null
      },
      "schedText": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultsTo": null
      },
      "date": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "defaultsTo": "2016-02-28T02:12:47.734Z"
      },
      "state": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "wait",
          "done",
          "failed"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "wait"
      },
      "retrytimes": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultsTo": 0
      },
      "loginfo": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "paper": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "desc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "owner"
      },
      "group": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "numfortest": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "photo": {
      "original": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "origSize": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "origName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "origType": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "small": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "medium": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "large": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "owner"
      },
      "album": {
        "type": "integer",
        "model": "event",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "album"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "privilege": {
      "userid": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "role": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultsTo": "user"
      },
      "scope": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "global",
          "group"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "group"
      },
      "groupid": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "creategroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "deletegroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "editgroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "createevent": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "deleteevent": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "editevent": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "addgroupmember": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "deletegroupmember": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "exportgroupmember": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "addeventmember": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "deleteeventmember": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "exporteventmember": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "uploadpaper": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "deletepaper": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "gettestreport": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "createtag": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "yes"
      },
      "deletetag": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "yes",
          "no"
        ],
        "defaultsTo": "no"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "tag": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "unique": true
      },
      "desc": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "uplevel": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "owner": {
        "type": "string",
        "model": "user",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "alias": "owner"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "user": {
      "fullname": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultsTo": "Anonymous"
      },
      "uid": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "dn": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "email": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "string",
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true
      },
      "userfd": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "createdAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        "type": "datetime"
      }
    },
    "comment_likeby__user_likedcomments": {
      "id": {
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true,
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "comment_likeby": {
        "type": "integer",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "references": "comment",
        "on": "id",
        "via": "user_likedcomments"
      },
      "user_likedcomments": {
        "type": "string",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "references": "user",
        "on": "id",
        "via": "comment_likeby"
      }
    },
    "event_user__user_events": {
      "id": {
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true,
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "event_user": {
        "type": "integer",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "references": "event",
        "on": "id",
        "via": "user_events"
      },
      "user_events": {
        "type": "string",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "references": "user",
        "on": "id",
        "via": "event_user"
      }
    },
    "group_user__user_group": {
      "id": {
        "primaryKey": true,
        "unique": true,
        "autoIncrement": true,
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "group_user": {
        "type": "integer",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "references": "group",
        "on": "id",
        "via": "user_group"
      },
      "user_group": {
        "type": "string",
        "foreignKey": true,
        "references": "user",
        "on": "id",
        "via": "group_user"
      }
    }
  },
  "counters": {
    "answer": {},
    "comment": {},
    "event": {},
    "group": {},
    "mail": {},
    "paper": {},
    "photo": {},
    "privilege": {
      "id": 9
    },
    "tag": {},
    "user": {},
    "comment_likeby__user_likedcomments": {},
    "event_user__user_events": {},
    "group_user__user_group": {}
  }
}
```

My question is what do I need to do in order to find the cause of this issue, and fix it?

I am a newbie on sails. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: this was caused by waterline version not the same. Data created by waterline 0.10.31 contains additional info compared with 0.10.21:   "constructor": {
          "\_\_super\_\_": {}
        },
        "toObject": {},
        "save": {},
        "destroy": {},
        "_defineAssociations": {},
        "_normalizeAssociations": {},
        "_cast": {},
        "validate": {},
        "toJSON": {},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use 'sails lift --silly' to check if anything wrong happened in sails lift, also to comment the codes in config/bootstrap.js except cb() to see if something wrong right after sails lift has caused the problem.